# String from ZonedTimeDate to java.util.Date without name of the month and day

Tags: java, date, datetime

I'm using a `ZonedDateTime` to get the current date-time. Because I dont want it with the time, I'm making it the format of `uuuu-MM-dd` and it gives me back a String as `2021-08-23`

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd" ); 
String date_string = zdt.format(formatter);
System.out.println(date_string);//2021-08-23
```

Now how can I convert this String `2021-08-23` to a java.util.Date? I want the date to look exactly like the String...
This is what I have tried but it won't get me the date looking like the string

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = formatter1.parse(date_string);
```

Will give me the date in this format: `Mon Aug 23 00:00:00 EEST 2021`... How can I
convert my string into a date and keep the date looking like the string?

Comment: Why do you need `java.util.Date`? Incidentally that class doesn't have a format. What you're seeing is the result of a default formatter being applied to it. You should be using your own formatter with `String s = formatter1.format(date)`

Comment: How can I do that with another date class?

Comment: Still not sure why you need `util.Date`

Comment: Like what @g00se mentioned, the `java.util.Date` is the object representation of the string date. If you're willing to override `java.util.Date`'s toString() method into your own custom Date, you can do that. However, I am not sure what's the point of doing it in the first place. If your goal is to have a date in a certain string format, then use a string and not the `Date` object.

Comment: A `ZonedDateTime` can be converted to an `Instant`, which has the `toDate()` method. However, you say you want a `Date`, but you have not explained why you want this. To me, this looks like an XY problem.

Comment: You may want to use `LocalDate`. It hasn’t got any inherent format either, but its `toString` method happens to produce the format you asked for `uuuu-MM-dd`, Use `zdt.toLocalDate()` for the conversion.

Comment: I recommend you neither use `SimpleDateFormat` nor `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and possibly other classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: What makes you think that you want an object with a specific format? It is ill advised because it’s mixing model and presentation, things that you should keep separate. And it is not possible with any class from the standard library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.now().toString()
```

> 2021-08-23

Better to specify desired/expected time zone rather than rely implicitly on the JVM’s current default time zone.

```
LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ).toString()
```

## Details

### `LocalDate`

If you want a date-only, use `LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate ld = myZonedDateTime.toLocalDate() ;
```

The `java.time.Date` class is terribly flawed, and should be avoided. The class was supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

If you must use this class to interoperable with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, you can convert back and forth between the legacy classes and their replacements. Look for  the new conversion methods added to the old classes.

### `java.util.Date` is *not* a date!

Understand that among its many flaws is the name of `java.util.Date`. That class represents not a date but a moment in time as seen in UTC. So its replacement is `java.time.Instant`, not `LocalDate`.

```
java.util.Date d = java.util.Date.from( myZonedDateTime.toInstant() );
```

You asked:

> How can I convert my string into a date and keep the date looking like the string?

Understand that none of these date-time classes are text. They have their own internally defined representation of a date-time value, not `String`.

It sounds like you simply want text in standard ISO 8601  format (YYYY-MM-DD) for a date-only value. The *java.time* classes use the standard ISO 8601 formats by default when generating/parsing strings. So no need to define a custom formatting pattern.

```
String output = myZonedDateTime.toLocalDate().toString() ;
```

### Date-time objects have no format, are not text

You asked:

> Now how can I convert this String 2021-08-23 to a java.util.Date? I want the date to look exactly like the String

What you request makes no sense.

A `java.util.Date` object is a date-time object, not text, not `String`. A `java.util.Date` object has no “format”.

Likewise, a `java.time.ZonedDateTime` object is a date-time object, not text, not `String`. A `java.time.ZonedDateTime`  object has no “format”.

And so too, a `java.time.LocalDate` object is a date object, not text, not `String`. A `java.time.LocalDate`  object has no “format”.

These date-time objects have a `toString` method that *generates* text representing the embedded value using a default format. But you should not conflate that generated text with the original date-time object.